# What is the default HTML document you use, and why?

Tags: html, standards

Meaning: doc-type, header, body, etc.

Comment: This is really a poll of sorts so it should be community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use xhtml 1.0 transitional because it is flexible, does what I need, and is relatively up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using "html" for the doc-type for a while:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

HTML5 is actually standard, even if I do prefer XML syntax and parsing.

Comment: **@Paul McMillan:** Agree HTML5 is the future, and laughed when I saw the "html" doc-type, really have a hard time understand how that's a standard... :-) ...even more funny is that w3.org "says" it's not a standard... ;-) **SOURCE:** http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 1):

I use XHTML 1.0 Strict because (a) I edit in plain-text and I like to see my markup validate because I have a perfectionist streak, (b) get things pixel-perfect across browsers (though it's less of a problem w/the slow demise of the accursed IE5.5 - [rendering differences with whitespace](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/) - need I say more?) and (c) strict markup tends to be forward-compatible (though I've got to say I'm not looking forward to the lax requirements posited by HTML5 ... [pSeUdO-CaMeLcAsE markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE) may be "valid" but it isn't easy on the eyes).

Comment: +1 on _Strict_ (HTML or XHTML) being forward-compatible. You can always drop to a Transitional DOCTYPE on the odd page that requires a deprecated attribute/tag.